# RxJS subscription management - avoid excess subscriptions

Tags: angular

How can I avoid excess subscriptions?

Is there a function that can be used for making sure any active subscriptions are unsubscribed?

```js
clickDown(e) {
  this.mouseMoveSubscription = fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'mousemove')
    .subscribe((e: MouseEvent) => {
      console.log(e);                                          
    });
}
```

Comment: Please have a look to `takeUntil` pattern, where you destroy subscription inside the `ngOnDestroy` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative could be to not subscribe observable manually.

Add `subscribe()` everywhere can be weary but that's because it's a bad practices

You could use `async` pipe provided by Angular.
This pipe will subscribe your datas and unsubscribe it when component will be destroyed.

**In component do not subscribe**

```
clickDown(e) {
  this.mouseMove$ = fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'mousemove');
}
```

**In template use `async`**

```
<div *ngIf="mouseMove$ | async as mouseMove">{{mouseMove}}</div>
```

Comment: It depends of your use case but just use `rxJS` operators. https://www.learnrxjs.io/

Comment: wouldn't I have to subscribe when using rxJS operators? your answer says not to subscribe

Comment: I don't really know rxJS, learning it now but if you included an example function handlers that'd help

Comment: not sure if this is the best answer but it looks the cleanest so I'll accept it

Comment: subscription will be done with `async`, RxJS operators will transform, combine or filter your event. If you want to understand different operators : https://rxmarbles.com/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're not using `async` pipes, then the currently accepted pattern is to use either `takeUntil` or `takeWhile` to manage your subscriptions `onDestroy`.

For example:

```js
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  unsubscribed = false; // <-- When the component loads, subscriptions are all active.

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(takeWhile(() => !this.unsubscribed)) // <-- Maintain this subscription while the component is not destroyed.
      .subscribe(() => {});
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribed = true; // <-- When the component is destroyed, unsubscribe all subscriptions bound to this.unsubscribed.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unsubscribe from previous and subscribe again if successful:

```
clickDown(e) {
    if(this.mouseMoveSubscription) this.mouseMoveSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.mouseMoveSubscription = fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'mousemove')
        .subscribe((e: MouseEvent) => {
            console.log(e);
        });
}
```

Also, unsubscribe when component destroys:

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if(this.mouseMoveSubscription) this.mouseMoveSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An even better approach will be to just use async pipes inside your components, Why?

1. They have auto unsubscribe support
2. They run the `markForCheck()` function for the change detection, so you can easily move your components to `onPush` strategy